# "Breaking down" a Chi square significant result in an r x c contigency table (SPSS)

Tags: chi-squared-test, spss, residuals, post-hoc

Having found my chi square is significant, comparing the behaviors of two horses' groups -stereotypers and non stereotypers (2x5 contingency table was the output result of cross tabulation), I'm looking for the partial significance and the contribution of every behavioral category in the overall significant result.

Using the column proportions test* (z-test) with the Bonferroni adjustment in order to detect the partial differences between my groups, would it be one and the same as checking for the values less than -1.96 and greater than 1.96 in the standardized or the adjusted standardized residuals rows?

*The column proportions test assigns a subscript letter to the categories of the column variable in the output table. For each pair of columns, the column proportions are compared using a z test. If a pair of values is significantly different, the values have different subscript letters assigned to them (taken from SPSS online help desk).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the expected frequencies and compare that with the observed frequencies to get an idea of where in your table the interesting patterns are.